# Comparing of two arraylists with object of the same type.How to get all elements of first list except for the ones contained in second list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm working on basic students system.Student has field of his sudy. Each field of Study has some subjects assigned. Each student gets 2 of theese subjects assigned. Now I need to get and print all the other subjects assigned to his field of study that are not assigned to him yet.
Here is what I tried

```
        ArrayList<Predmet> dostupnePredmety = new ArrayList<Predmet>();
        for (Predmet vPredmet : this.loggedStudent.getOdbor().getPredmety()) {
            for ( Predmet sPredmet : this.loggedStudent.getPredmety()) {
                if (vPredmet != sPredmet) {
                    dostupnePredmety.add(vPredmet);
                }
            }
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (Predmet dPredmet : dostupnePredmety) {
            System.out.println("[" + i + "]" + dPredmet.getNazov() + " " + dPredmet.getPocetStudentov() + "/" + dPredmet.getCapacity());
            i++;
        }
```

It didn't work because the second for loop I used compares element of first list with every single one of the second list so it adds all the elements.Even those I don't want. It's pretty obvious because the object from first list would need to be the same as all the elements of second list for this to work. I couldn't figure out the right solution.

Comment: Hi, may we know which is the method that returns all subjects assigned to his field of study, and which is the method at returns the subjects already assigned to the student?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible solutions, I recommend the second one as it is computationally more efficient.

Pre-requisite:

For both solutions, you will need to first [override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts)

Solution 1 (shorter code):

```
    for (Predmet vPredmet : this.loggedStudent.getOdbor().getPredmety()) {
            if (!this.loggedStudent.getPredmety().contains(vPredmet)) {
                dostupnePredmety.add(vPredmet);
            }
    }
```

Solution 2 (Most computationally efficient):

```
    Set<Predmet> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (Predmet predmety: this.loggedStudent.getPredmety()) {
        set.add(predmety);
    }
    for (Predmet vPredmet : this.loggedStudent.getOdbor().getPredmety()) {
            if (!set.contains(vPredmet)) {
                dostupnePredmety.add(vPredmet);
            }
    }
```